# Get a value from key=value text file (without sections) in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I want to obtain some values from a text file ( Database Name, Username, Password),  I found a way to do it, but not sure if is the best way, cause the password return with some kind of "tab spaces" at the end, is this the correct way or there is another way to do it more easy?

This is my text file:

```
javax.persistence.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://address=(protocol=tcp)(host=127.0.0.1) 
(port=3306)/A_DBNAME
javax.persistence.jdbc.user=A_USER
javax.persistence.jdbc.password=A_PASSWORD
```

And this is my code:

```pascal
function StrSplit(Text: String; Separator: String): TArrayOfString;
var
  i, p: Integer;
  Dest: TArrayOfString; 
begin
  i := 0;
  repeat
    SetArrayLength(Dest, i+1);
    p := Pos(Separator,Text);
    if p > 0 then begin
      Dest[i] := Copy(Text, 1, p-1);
      Text := Copy(Text, p + Length(Separator), Length(Text));
      i := i + 1;
    end else begin
      Dest[i] := Text;
      Text := '';
    end;
  until Length(Text)=0;
  Result := Dest
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
 file : AnsiString;
 dbName, pass, user : TArrayOfString;
begin
  LoadStringFromFile( ExpandConstant('{src}\jdbcfile.txt'), file);  
  user := StrSplit(file, 'javax.persistence.jdbc.user=');
  user := StrSplit(user[1],'javax.persistence.jdbc.password=')         
  MsgBox('User: '+user[0],mbInformation,MB_OK);
  pass := StrSplit(file,'javax.persistence.jdbc.password=');  
  MsgBox('Pass: '+pass[1],mbInformation,MB_OK);
  dbName := StrSplit(file, ')/');
  dbName := StrSplit(dbName[1],'javax.persistence.jdbc.user=');
  MsgBox('dbName: '+dbName[0],mbInformation,MB_OK);
end;
```

Comment: There's no `StrSplit` function in Inno Setup. It must be your function. So you have not posted [mcve].

Comment: Also there's no generic way to get "value" from a text file. It all depends on a format of your "text file". I do not see any distinct format of your text file. It is really "broken" the way you have posted in your question? Aren't the first two lines actually a single line? Are the other lines really indented?

Comment: Im sorry, I just edited the question, and yes, the first two lines are a single line,
(there is just 3 lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imo, it's conceptually wrong to try to parse the overall file structure (`key=value`) and the individual key value (`.url`) at the same time. Moreover you rely on a specific key order in the file, what is wrong too.

- Start by creating a function that retrieves a value of specific key.
- And only after that, parse a value of a specific key. As the `.url` key has path-like structure, you can "abuse" [`ExtractFileName` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=extractfilename).

```pascal
function GetKeyValue(Lines: TStrings; Key: string): string;
var
  I, P: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to Lines.Count - 1 do
  begin
    P := Pos('=', Lines[I]);
    if (P > 0) and (CompareText(Trim(Copy(Lines[I], 1, P - 1)), Key) = 0) then
    begin
      Result := Trim(Copy(Lines[I], P + 1, Length(Lines[I]) - P));
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  { Implicitly returns an empty string, if the key does not exist. }
  { Alternatively you can also throw an exception by using RaiseException function, }
  { or return some default value [by adding an additional parameter to this function]. }
end;
```

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  Lines: TStringList;
  DbName, User, Password: string;
begin
  Lines := TStringList.Create;
  Lines.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{src}\jdbcfile.txt'));

  DbName := ExtractFileName(GetKeyValue(Lines, 'javax.persistence.jdbc.url'));
  User := GetKeyValue(Lines, 'javax.persistence.jdbc.user');
  Password := GetKeyValue(Lines, 'javax.persistence.jdbc.password');

  Lines.Free;
  { ... }
end;
```